# Converting values and changing the unit in Stackdriver

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

My Stackdriver chart shows like this

[image]

The Y axis here is actually the number of milliseconds and I want to display it as number of days

```
e.g. 3G milliseconds ~ 34 days
```

So, basically I want to do this operation ((3 x 10<sup>9</sup>) x 10<sup>-3</sup>)/86400 and change the Y axis label to days.
Can I do that in stackdriver?

I have the following settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As currently you can only [rescale](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/chart-view-options#logscale-option) the chart's Y-values logarithmically, I advise you to open a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with the information that you've provided here, so the proper team will evaluate its implementation.

I hope this information helps you.